# What is your public repository/directory site for sysadmin scripts?

Tags: scripting, repository

Please write the languages/platforms supported if the site doesn't allow every kind of scripts.
Why you use it? Why is it a good source?
Talk about the major weakness of the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is what you're looking for, but the closest thing I can think of would be [Monitoring Exchange](http://www.monitoringexchange.org/), which keeps scripts that enable admins to enhance their remote monitoring.

There's also a thread on [HP's forums](http://forums13.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?admit=109447627+1260653701528+28353475&threadId=51050) devoted to sysadmin scripts, but it's pretty old.

If you want tips on writing good scripts, my fellow blogger Bob Plankers wrote a column with great tips [here](http://lonesysadmin.net/2006/03/27/how-to-write-a-good-script/).

Comment: Exactly. Monitoring Exchange seems very good. Thanks.